# Deleting 'QNetworkReply *' returned by QNetworkAccessManager::post

Tags: qt, qt4

QNetworkAccessManager::post function returns network reply object, is caller required to delete this or network access manager will take care of deleting it.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html):

> Note: After the request has finished,
>   it is the responsibility of the user
>   to delete the QNetworkReply object at
>   an appropriate time. Do not directly
>   delete it inside the slot connected to
>   finished(). You can use the
>   deleteLater() function.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in slot if readyRead

```
   reply->abort();
    reply->deleteLater();
    reply->manager()->deleteLater();
```