# QNetworkReply wrapper stored into QList makes program finish unexpectedly?

Tags: c++, qt

In order to learn Qt I'm testing some Qt (5.3.1) classes; for now I'm testing some of the classes provided on the network package such as `QNetworkAccessManager`, `QNetworkReply`, etc...

I'm using Qt creator (3.1.2) to compile a simple program which uses the following `QNetworkReply` wrapper:

```
struct Request {
    Request(QNetworkReply *const &a_reply) : m_reply(a_reply) {
        qDebug() << "Build  " << hex << int(this) << hex << int(m_reply);
    }
    ~Request() {
        if (m_reply) m_reply->deleteLater();
        qDebug() << "Destroy" << hex << int(this) << hex << int(m_reply);
    }
    QNetworkReply *m_reply;
};
```

All the wrapped network replies are stored on a `QList` named `R`:

```
QList<Request> R;
```

And are created through the following function:

```
void get(const QString &a_url) {
    QNetworkRequest request(a_url);
    R.push_back(NetworkAccessManager.get(request));
}
```

The `NetworkAccessManager` is an instance of `QNetworkAccessManager` which lies outside the `main` function (the same goes for the list `R`):

```
QList<Request> R;

QNetworkAccessManager NetworkAccessManager;

void done(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        qDebug() << "Reply!" << reply->readAll();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Error!" << reply->errorString();
    }

    for (QList<Request>::iterator request = R.begin(), lastRequest = R.end(); request != lastRequest; ++request) {
        if (request->m_reply == reply) {
            R.erase(request);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    // Default "hello world" qml file:
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    QObject::connect(&NetworkAccessManager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, done);

    get("http://us.battle.net/api/wow/achievement/2144");
    get("http://us.battle.net/api/wow/achievement/2145");
    get("http://us.battle.net/api/wow/achievement/2146");

    return app.exec();
}
```

The program pasted above, produces the following output:

```
Build   28fdc8 1be843b8
Destroy 28fdc8 1be843b8
Build   28fdc8 1be84558
Destroy 28fdc8 1be84558
Build   28fdc8 1be84638
Destroy 28fdc8 1be84638
```

So, it seems that the same instance of `Request` is managing different `QNetworkReply` pointers (the `this` pointer printed is the same while the `QNetworkReply` changes) and no `"Reply!"` nor `"Error!"` is shown; after click on the close button of the application window, the program crashes about 8 or 10 seconds later printing:

> The program has unexpectedly finished.
>   C:\Code\build-test-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\test.exe crashed

Removing the `deleteLater()` instruction on `~Request` produces the following output:

```
Build   28fdc8 1be78078
Destroy 28fdc8 1be78078
Build   28fdc8 1be78218
Destroy 28fdc8 1be78218
Build   28fdc8 1be782e8
Destroy 28fdc8 1be782e8
Reply! "the expected json for http://us.battle.net/api/wow/achievement/2145"
Destroy 1be782c8 1be78218
Reply! "the expected json for http://us.battle.net/api/wow/achievement/2146"
Destroy 1be78398 1be782e8
Reply! "the expected json for http://us.battle.net/api/wow/achievement/2144"
Destroy 1be781f8 1be78078
```

And the program does not crash anymore, but it seems that a copy of `Request` is made somewhere for each `get` call according to the 3 exttra `Destroy` messages. And to make things worse I'm not doing the `deleteLater()` anymore ([which seems to be mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1515825/499359)), so I've placed the `deleteLater()` at the end of the `done` function:

```
void done(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    // do stuf...

    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

With good results (no application crash), but I'm worried because I don't get what's happening, so I wonder if any of you would be so kind to answer the following questions:

- Why the function `done` isn't called if the `deleteLater()` is placed in `~Request`?
- Why the call to `done` (`"Reply!"` output) is done AFTER the call to `~Request` (`"Destroy"` output)?
- Why the pointer `this` of `Request` (printed on construction) have the same value on each call? (maybe due to some optimization?).
- Where (and why) a copy of a `Request` is made?
- Where is the best location to call the `deleteLater()` of each `QNetworkReply`.

Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion without reading the whole Q: wrap the pointer in QPointer, so you can check if the object is deleted.

Comment: `QList` requires the value type to be an "[assignable data type](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html#assignable-data-type)", meaning it needs a default constructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator. Since you haven't provided any of those, you have the compiler defaults (which will do member-wise assigns/copies). Thus, if `QList` makes and destroys any temporary internal copies of your `Request` structure it will end up deleting the `QNetworkReply` instances while you still have pointers to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Andrew Medico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19405/andrew-medico) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387697/qnetworkreply-wrapper-stored-into-qlist-makes-program-finish-unexpectedly#comment39597074_25387697) doesn't answer any of my questions but pointed me on the right direction.

In fact, according to the documentation linked by Andrew (emphasis mine):

> The values stored in the various containers can be of any assignable data type. To qualify, a type ***must* provide a default constructor, a copy constructor, and an assignment operator**.

And so it did my `Request` struct (implicitly not explicity, that's Ok for me though), but in order to accomplish all the *must* of the `QList` contained type I've decided to provide the missing parts:

```
struct Request {
    Request() :
    m_reply(nullptr) {
        qDebug() << "Default" << hex << int(this) << hex << int(m_reply);
    }

    Request(QNetworkReply *const &a_reply) :
    m_reply(a_reply) {
        qDebug() << "Build  " << hex << int(this) << hex << int(m_reply);
    }

    Request(const Request &a_request) :
    m_reply(a_request.m_reply) {
        qDebug() << "Copy   " << hex << int(this) << hex << int(m_reply);
    }

    Request &operator =(const Request &a_request) {
        qDebug() << "Assign " << hex << int(this) << hex << int(m_reply = a_request.m_reply); return *this;
    }

    ~Request() {
        qDebug() << "Destroy" << hex << int(this) << hex << int(m_reply);
    }
    QNetworkReply *m_reply;
};
```

After that, the output changed and all becomes crystal clear:

```
Build   28fdc8 1ba5bda0
Copy    1ba5bf20 1ba5bda0
Destroy 28fdc8 1ba5bda0
Build   28fdc8 1ba5bf40
Copy    1ba5bff0 1ba5bf40
Destroy 28fdc8 1ba5bf40
Build   28fdc8 1ba5c020
Copy    1ba5c0c0 1ba5c020
Destroy 28fdc8 1ba5c020
Reply! "the expected json for http://us.battle.net/api/wow/achievement/2145"
Destroy 1ba5bff0 1ba5bf40
Reply! "the expected json for http://us.battle.net/api/wow/achievement/2144"
Destroy 1ba5bf20 1ba5bda0
Reply! "the expected json for http://us.battle.net/api/wow/achievement/2146"
Destroy 1ba5c0c0 1ba5c020
```

So, let's answer the questions:

> Why the function `done` isn't called if the `deleteLater()` is placed in `~Request`?

Every time a new `Request` is pushed into the `R` container (`R.push_back(NetworkAccessManager.get(request))`) happens the following:

1. A R-value `Request` object is created (`"Build"` output).
2. The R-value is inserted in `R` via copy constructor (`"Copy"` output).
3. The R-value which we copied from is destroyed (`"Destroy"` output).

The destruction performed on the 3rd step causes all the problems: because the `QNetworkReply` pointer managed by the R-value and the copied contained `Request` are the same so, calling the `deleteLater()` placed in `~Request` causes that the contained `Request` starts to manage a deleted (or future-deleted) resource! That's why `done` isn't called, the fact is that there's no `QNetworkReply` to wait to complete (it was deleted!).

It's kind of a shame that the QList doesn't provides an [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_back).

> Why the call to `done` (`"Reply!"` output) is done AFTER the call to `~Request` (`"Destroy"` output)?

The `"Destroy"` output corresponds to the destruction of the R-value created in order to insert a `Request` into the `R` container, the `"Reply!"` output happens after the insertion, so it's after the destruction of the R-value and then, the contained `Request` is destroyed (`"Destroy"` output AFTER the `"Reply!"` output).

> Why the pointer `this` of `Request` (printed on construction) have the same value on each call? (maybe due to some optimization?).

The repeated address corresponds to the address of the R-value used to populate the `R` container, my guess is that the same address is used to construct this R-value at each call as a some kind of optimization.

> Where (and why) a copy of a `Request` is made?

See the first answer.

> Where is the best location to call the `deleteLater()` of each `QNetworkReply`.

At the end of the function `done` should be Ok.